# how can i save my workbook in VBA without stopping the macro from running?

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code that is calling this method after a certain amount of time has passed using application.ontime,

```
Sub run()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Calculate

Cells(2, 5).Value = Cells(2, 5).Value + 1

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

however, after the ActiveWorkbook.Save line, the macros just stop running. how can i continue to run my macros after saving the workbook, or maybe call a macro upon saving? I'm using excel 2013 btw

here is my macro that calls run:

```
Sub every30seconds()

runTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")

Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=runTime, Procedure:="run", schedule:=True

If Cells(2, 5).Value = 2 Then
   Application.OnTime runTime, "run", , False
   Cells(2, 5).Value = Cells(2, 5).Value - 2
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is your macro code to call the run sub? Do you have any code in your subs `Workbook_AfterSave` or  `Workbook_BeforeSave`

Comment: Have you tried adding a line to the above code such as `MsgBox "File has been saved."` after the save command to verify your *assumption* that the code just stops running?

Comment: @dbmitch okay i just added my macro that calls run sub, and no i don't, i tried using workbook_aftersave before and it didn't work. could u give me an example?

Comment: @Ralph this is all test code for continuing my macro after saving, increasing the value of Cells(2,5) is to test this out and it doesn't work after calling workbook.save. all macros end

Comment: Shouldn't the code to insert the procedure in 30 seconds be in your run sub? This should be moved into run: `runTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")

Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=runTime, Procedure:="run", schedule:=True`

Comment: do you want this to literally to run every 30 seconds? If so, you need a loop in one or the other macros. As written the macro will only run once.

Comment: @dbmitch i have three different subs, every 30 seconds, every 15 seconds and every 5 seconds, and i want to have a button for each that calls run. i've tried this and it works but right when i inserted the workbook.save it didn't work anymore, and its because saving the workbook stops all macros. i searched up documentation for workbook_aftersave and it didn't work for me. are you supposed to use workbook_beforesave along with it in order to make it work?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman the problem im facing is that workbook.save breaks all macros. will adding a loop fix that?

Comment: so you're saying that this line `Cells(2, 5).Value = Cells(2, 5).Value - 2`  does not run after calling the `run` macro?

Comment: Your problem is not that the save stops macros.  The problem is that you are executing the "run" command only once.  I just created a new workbook, copied your code into it, added a `MsgBox "Hi"` and a `every30seconds` after your `ActiveWorkbook.Save`, changed your test for 2 to be a test for 5 (just so that it would run a few more times), then ran the code.  It ran produced 5 "Hi" messages and left me with 3 in cell E2.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Assuming the initial value of E2 is zero, the OP's code will only set it to 1 and then stop.  It never gets back to the "every30seconds" code to test whether E2 is equal to 2.

Comment: @YowE3K - i was just picking that up myself in my testing :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman sorry about that man! you were right all along

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application.Ontime Method does not allow you to schedule something to happen multiple times in the future.  It only allows you to set something to happen once.

I believe the code you are after is

```
Sub run()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Calculate

    Cells(2, 5).Value = Cells(2, 5).Value + 1

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    every30seconds
End Sub   

Sub every30seconds()
    If Cells(2, 5).Value <> 2 Then
        runTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")

        Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=runTime, Procedure:="run", schedule:=True
    Else
        Cells(2, 5).Value = Cells(2, 5).Value - 2
    End If
End Sub
```